# How set action bar options menu when a nested fragment becomes visible?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to be able to clear the action bar menu and inflate a new one from within a nested fragment when the particular nested fragment becomes visible.

My app consists of a main activity with a ViewPager which uses a FragmentPagerAdapter. This ViewPager has 4 root fragments which are simply blank FrameLayouts (one in each page) that each contain and swap out nested fragments. These nested fragments can be different or the same type (think about how Instagram can show a different profile view in multiple tabs). This means that I can't use the onPrepareOptionsMenu to inflate menus on page swipe, because I won't know which nested fragment is in the root fragment of each page. Additionally, I have set the offScreenPageLimit to 3, so that I can swipe between root fragments without reloading. This means that I can't just inflate the menu from within the nested fragments, because then all four nested nested fragment's menus will appear.

The ideal solution would be able to inflate menus from within the nested fragments through some sort of callback that gets executed when the nested fragment is literally displayed on the screen, e.g. when we swipe to the page containing the root fragment which contains the nested fragment, or we swap the nested fragment for another within the root fragment of a page. Does anyone have a design solution to the problem I'm having? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> The ideal solution would be able to inflate menus from within the nested fragments through some sort of callback that gets executed when the nested fragment is literally displayed on the screen.

1. Create a menu for the fragment in the menu directory
2. Report that this fragment has options menu [have a look](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))
3. Then just inflate it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)), and override [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) and when the fragment will become visible those menu options from fragment menu will be added to activity menu options.

Comment: Not quite. That was naturally the first thing I tried. When I do this then ALL of my fragments menu items will populate the action bar at once, since all four visible fragments in my view pager are created at the same time and run concurrently.

Comment: Ok, so you know the drill, then create a fragment without UI and add it just for the menu inflating purpose.

Comment: Thanks for following up! Doesn't that pose the same problem though? If I add a fragment with no UI that handles inflating a menu into each of my root fragments, then all four menus will be inflated and I'll have all of the items in my action bar, since all of the UI-less fragments will be running concurrently. If that's not what you mean then maybe I'm not understanding your suggestion.

Comment: I mean to create only one totally separate fragment  without UI (fifth) (onCreateView() returns null) in addition to your 4 root fragments. Though it will work only if all of your 4 root fragments have similar menu items. And then you can treat those menu items depending on what your fragments are visible at the moment and so on... But probably I did not understand your use-cases totally clear.